# Using the input line instead of prompt popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that allows user to enter a text into the input field and this text appears on the story board.

I'm trying to understand how to connect this text to the switches and if\else statements to let using the input field instead of prompt popup.

I have tried to use a global variable with empty value that should change its value to be equal to the user's input value every time the user is entering a new text, and after that make it to null again, but it didn't work.

```js
// This function will show needed text on the story board:
var showText = function(text) {
  $("#storyBoard").append(text + "<br />");
  // When a total amount of text inside story board will be more then the size of a
  // story board window, this script will automaticly scroll down every time when
  // appending additional text.
  var element = document.getElementById("storyBoard");
  element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
};

// This is a button click function. When user clicks the Enter button all the text
// from the input line appends to the story board.
$("#btn").click(function() {
  var btnClick = $("input[name=myInput]").val();
  $("#storyBoard").append(btnClick + "<br>");
  $("input[name=myInput]").val("");
  var element = document.getElementById("storyBoard");
  element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
});
var mission1 = function() {
    if (userIn !== "") {
      var story = userIn.toLowerCase();
      switch (story) {
        case "yes":
          showText("Yes");
          showText("Welcome aboard!");
          selectChar();
          showText("You met your old friend that for some reason starting to fight against you!");
          break;
        case "no":
          showText("Your choise is no.");
          break
        default:
          showText("default");
          break;
      }
    } else {
      // I think that here I can put a function that will somehow "wait" for user's
      // input from the input field and then call the mission1() again... 
      // But if so, i will have to repeat this function every time, and I prefer no
      // to repeat the same code.
    };

    mission1();
```

Comment: I really dont understand what you want to achive. Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/h1vedv46/

Comment: I'm still trying to use this in my code, to get the result i need, but it looks like what i looked for so much. And i'm very thankfull to you for your help.